# conditional checkout form woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In the woocommerce checkout page, how to make an input required if some other input field has value? For Example, suppose the form has a Company and a VAT Number Field (Both are initially not required). But, if the user provides a value to the company field, the VAT number field will also be required. Any idea how i can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: you have everything on this official WooCommerce tutorial: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook. Try the following

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( $_POST['company_field'] && !$_POST['vat_field'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your error message.' ), 'error' );
}
```